# Delete second dot/comma in EditText

Tags: java, android

I want to add a few numbers together from an EditText.
I want it to work both for european and other countries so it has to work with commas and dots as seperators.
The problem is the app crashes if the user accidently puts in 2 or more dots or a dot and a comma.
Is there a short way to check and delete the unnecessary seperators?
Thanks a lot!

This is my code so far:

```
android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
android:digits="0123456789.,"

.replace(",", "."));
```

Comment: You can not worry about this all together and load a JavaScript WebView for the EditText so when a user presses `submit` the string from the EditText is evaluated as a mathematical expression using JS (I did this with my very first calculator app for Android, not the best solution but know it is easy and very possible). The other/easiest pure Java way would be to use `replaceAll()` method for the string to remove the extra characters you want after you have determined there are unneeded separators. Or you can show an error Toast if your logic finds extra separators and let the user fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick,

```
.replaceAll("\\,+", ".").replaceAll("\\.+", ".")
```

if there are any commas first one will replace all the commas with dots and the second one will replace all the dots with a one dot

Comment: Thanks, this works fine for something like 1...1 or 1,,2 but it still crashes on something like 1,1,

Comment: @einUsername So the dot can be only exist in the end of a String? There can't be any Strings like 11.2?

Comment: It works if there are one/multiple dots in a row in the middle of the string like 0..0. But it doesnt work if the dots are seperated with a number like 0.0.0 or if the dot is at the start or end of the string like .0 and 0.

Comment: Yes. I get that part. I just want to clarify few things. Is it possible for numbers like 11.21 as digits? If its possible, then if someone enters 11.2.1 as digits how can we know 11.21 or 112.1 is the correct one? that would be impossible right?

Comment: 11.21 works. Yes there is no way to tell which one they mean. But lets assume the first dot was the correct one.

Comment: Or maybe just show an error message if there are more than one dots/commas.

Comment: Yes. We can't decide scenarios like that. Best thing is to show an error message and let the user decide

Answer (score 1):

This will replace the whole string with 0. It's not pretty but at least it keeps the app from crashing. I guess this will have to do for now ;)

if (string.getText().toString().matches(".*\..*\..*")) {string.setText("0");}